# Represent graphically the set of complex numbers that verifies $|z| = \pi + arg(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions

This is a problem on my textbook on complex analysis.

> Represent graphically the set of complex numbers that verifies the
>   equality: $|z| = \pi + arg(z)$ where arg is the principal value of the argument function.

I've plotted the set with wolframalpha [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%20%3D%20pi%20%2B%202%20arctg%28%20y%2F%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%2Bx%29%29) but I don't know how to do it by hand.

Comment: Be cautious: the graphic representation of Wolfram has spurious parts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider all complex numbers with the same argument $\theta$: $Ae^{i\theta}$. The one that is in your set is when $A = \pi + \theta$.

So the set of numbers has the form
$$z = (\pi+\theta)e^{i\theta}$$

And is part of a spiral, subject to the range of $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$.

Answer (score 2):

Work in polar coordinates. Write $z=re^{i\theta}$ with $r\ge 0$ and $-\pi<\theta\le\pi$; then the equation in polar coordinates is $r=\theta+\pi$, whose graph is an [Archimedean spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral). It’s not hard to plot points by hand for a few nice values of $\theta$ to get a decent sketch.